# what is the role of the wallet?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, wallets, eoa

I'm working on an ethereum blockchain project where people want to make reservations in a city. I'm in this situatin[image]

I have many users booking, but I want all these bookings to be collected by a single EOA. This EOA sends the transactions to the smart contract.

- How does the EOA collect requests from users?
- In this scenario I don't understand the role of the wallet. Do I need the wallet to sign the transactions that the single EOA sends?

Comment: What is EOA? If EOA is one, then why do we need a blockchain?

Comment: @MadJackal [Externally Owned Account, a.k.a. a regular Ethereum address.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/what-is-an-eoa-account)