# What are some reliable multisig wallet solutions for Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, wallets, multisignature, smart-contract-wallets

so I partnered up with 4 people that we work on a project.

It is not that we dont have some basic level of trust with each other but we would like to have some added reassurance when it comes to revenue distribution.

Currently, our project doesn't have a significant eth income stream and we just use Disperse to distribute our cuts.

But we believe in the project's potential and thus there is some concern about what happens if our income increases significantly.

Like one or more partners may conspire to just reroute the bulk of the revenue and disappear.

So I would like to get information about how we could either directly (with a standalone multisign client) or indirectly (using a atleast somewhat trustworthy 3rd party e.g binance)

To route our revenue via a mutually controlled smart contract to a single place, which said "single place" in turn (be it a multisign solution I am not aware of or a 3rd party service) not allow the participants to move tokens unless all the participants agree for that transaction to be done.

I thank you in advance.

Comment: Check out [gnosis-safe.io](https://gnosis-safe.io/). It's securing billions of dollar worth of Ethereum assets.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg yea but as far as I can see there is no way to achieving my goal (no funds to be moved from the wallets unless everybody signes) like the way I understand gnosis works is that you add 2 3rd party wallets (e.g two metamask ones) and they create a smart contract which WITHIN THAT you can't move funds unless both parties sign, but one wallet owner could just open his metamask app and transfer the contents of that wallet outside gnosis so this defeats the purpose.

Comment: It is not possible to achieve what you want. Read about [what is an 'EOA' account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/what-is-an-eoa-account).

Answer (score 2):

A really good option is Gnosis.

Find more info here:
https://gnosis-safe.io/#getting-started

to create a wallet on Gnosis Safe, go here:
https://gnosis-safe.io/app/#/welcome

Comment: yea but as far as I can see there is no way to achieving my goal (no funds to be moved from the wallets unless everybody signes) like the way I understand gnosis works is that you add 2 3rd party wallets (e.g two metamask ones) and they create a smart contract which WITHIN THAT you can't move funds unless both parties sign, but one wallet owner could just open his metamask app and transfer the contents of that wallet outside gnosis so this defeats the purpose.

Comment: Gnosis Safe does exactly, what you describe. If all funds go into that multisig contract and you set the threshold to 4, then all 4 have to sign to move any funds (ETH, Tokens and NFTs) out of that wallet.

Comment: do they have an API to their Gnosis Safe? All I see is this:  https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/. I'm looking for functions like: `createContractWallet` `addAccount` `removeAccount` `addFunds`

Answer (score 0):

Check out TotalSig - https://www.totalsig.com/

It is a multichain multisig wallet that is based on MPC (a very hot topic nowadays). One important thing is that you can create wallets with any n-of-m schema there. It supports Bitcoin multisigs, Ethereum multisigs, Tron multisigs and more. You can also store tokens, NFTs and interact with dApps (Web3 applications).

A great advantage of MPC is you DO NOT need to deploy a smart contract. Multisig wallet creation happens off-chain, a bit similar to how it is done in traditional Bitcoin multisigs. It saves ~20-100 USD per wallet on Ethereum network, comparing to Gnosis wallet for example. Also, MPC transactions does not reveal wallet participants, so it provides better privacy that other multisig wallets.

In the nutshell it works the following way: all participants generate their own private keys, then they derive their group public keys. When they need to sign a transaction they calculate their share of the signature (shares of `r` and `s` values). This way they literally can just sum up their signature shares and get a group signature.

You can think of it, and use it as a replacement to, MetaMask, which can be controlled by up to 32 people, with opportunity to create Bitcoin, Tron and other wallets in the same app.

Disclaimer: I am a developer of this wallet. Feel free to reach out to me to provide feedback or request new features.