# Safest way to manage my assets from a smart contract

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ethereumjs, smart-contract-wallets, smart-lock

I am working in a develop for manage all the assets of my company. Actually we are using fireblocks for have all of our asset safety.
But the problem with this service is, that they do not have solidity api to interact with our wallets/vaults.

I need to have part of my assets in a safest smart contract to interact automaticcaly from my app.

The first option that I tought was Gnosis Safe.

Do you know other smart contract that provide my a secure way to intereract with my assets.

I do not want to  write my code of this smart contract, I would like to use some tested samart contract.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are some reliable multisig wallet solutions for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107000/what-are-some-reliable-multisig-wallet-solutions-for-ethereum)

Comment: Have you tried BitGo? Also, have you already written your Smart Contracts?